# Sign in to Azure AD using ADAL for .NET on Windows 10 within a corporate AD

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

Recently, I faced with the following behavior of the [ADAL for .NET](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/), which is specific for this environment: Windows 10 + a corporate active directory.

```
...

authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

...

var tokenResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
    resourceId,
    clientId,
    redirectUri,
    new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, parentWindow));
```

Using the `PromptBehavior.Auto` I can't sign in with a proper account because the ADAL library doesn't show the sign in window (on the screenshot) but rather uses the account I'm currently logged into Windows 10 (which eventually and obviously leads to access denied error since the account I'm logged into Windows is not in the Azure AD I'm connecting to).

The interesting thing is that the same code works as expected for my colleagues who are working on Windows 7\8.[image]

So, what's the possible problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PromptBehavior.Auto` will try to use an active token, but if not will show the login page if the refresh token is invalid/expired or credentials are required.  You likely have a session that needs to be re-authenticated for one reason or another, and are getting prompted to sign in again for the user in the cache. If you're domain joined on the Win 10 device, it will automatically use that user.

You should be able to hit the `Use another account` button to sign in a different user.  Alternatively, you can use `PromptBehavior.Always` which will ignore the cache and allow you to sign in a fresh user.

Comment: "If you're domain joined on the Win 10 device, it will automatically use that user." Is it applicable for Win 10 only? As I stated before, Win 7\8 doesn't try to use the domain user but just shows the sign in popup (assuming it's a first sign in and 'PromptBehavior.Auto' option is being used). How can I turn off this behavior of a Win 10 domain account being used by default (maybe, some windows setting) for 'PromptBehavior.Auto'? Obviously, I can use 'PromptBehavior.Always' or 'PromptBehavior.RefreshSession' values to have the popup be shown and sign in with a needed account.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to disable this without using `PromptBehavior.Always`.  It's possible there's a setting in Windows, but not sure.