# AADSTS9000411: The request is not properly formatted. The parameter 'prompt' is duplicated

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I am using adal.js for implementing the login to my app. For some reason, I cannot use admin_consent so I am using `prompt=consent` in `extraQueryParameter`.

I am getting the prompt as well but after accepting the same it is giving an error

> AADSTS9000411: The request is not properly formatted. The parameter 'prompt' is duplicated.

When checked the query contains 2 prompts

```
prompt=consent and
prompt=none
```

Can someone please help why I am getting prompt=none when I am using "consent"?

Any help would be appreciated. Screenshots attached for reference.

[prompt duplicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpxK8.png)

[prompt error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXB9U.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Prompt behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-differences-adal-net#prompt-behavior) equivalents in  MSAL.NET  to that of  prompt behavior in ADAL.NET :

- `PromptBehavior.RefreshSession`   in adal equivalents prompt value
  `Consent` in msal.net which forces the user to consent again to all
  permissions when using acquireToken method.

Or

- Try to use `PromptBehavior.Always` which  ignores the cache and allows
  to sign in as a fresh new user.

**Reference:**

1. [c# - Sign in to Azure AD using ADAL for .NET  - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42789018/sign-in-to-azure-ad-using-adal-for-net-on-windows-10-within-a-corporate-ad)
2. [azureactivedirectory-library-for-js issues](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/630)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to resolve the issue I was facing.

This "prompt" error can be fixed in two ways-
EITHER upgrade the library to version greater than 1.0.16.
OR use "consentType=Principal" in extraQueryParameter config for giving user consent.

in lower versions-
"By design, the prompt parameter is not configurable by the user. AcquireToken happens in a hidden iframe and its prompt value cannot be anything other than none."